# Difference between 「 ただ」, 「たった」, 「ただ　～だけ」, and 「ただし」

Tags: usage

I translate these words as either "only, just, simply".

I'd like to know how I could differentiate these 4 ways (i.e., when I use that one, and when I use the other).

Examples:

> - たったひとつの恋　(Dorama)
> - ただの子供だ
> - ただ待つだけだ
> - よし, この 10 万円は君にあげよう. ただし, これ以上はお断わりだよ.
>     ...
>     ... so on

Comment: Actually, ただし usually means ‘but’, ‘however’, etc. I'd add 〜しか〜ない to the list of words you're asking about though.

Comment: btw why is ただ待つだけだ grammatical? shouldn't it be ただ(noun/gerund)だけだ ?

Comment: hmm. i thought of "It's just wait!" (there's no other thing unless wating) ^^ あってるかどうかわからないけど.

Comment: I cannot imagine the context where ただ蛇だ is used.  What is the context?

Comment: @Pacerier - だけ attaches to the 連体形 of 活用語. ただ ain't got nothing to do with it.

Comment: @daniel tomio - "It's just wait!" is ungrammatical. It's more along the lines of "We have only to wait.", "I just wait.", etc. You could say "It is but to wait.", but it sounds a little stilted in everyday speech.

Comment: @rdb btw do you mean to say that 待つ is the 連体形 of 活用語? (this is quite confusing)  because isn't 待つ the "dictionary form" ? Is 待つだけだ grammatical?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. I corrected now (or I think I corrected. lol). I put ただの虫だ (it's just a simply insect). hope you all could understand now. ^^

Comment: ただ待つだけだ: we can but wait!~ Maybe it's the meaning I wanted. I don't know, cuz a japanese person gave me this sentence when I asked her the trasnlation of "You have to wait, only this" or "you don't have other thing to do unless waiting". (sorry if I made confusion).

Comment: @Pacerier - 待つ is an inflecting word, that is, it changes form according to grammatical rules. This class of word is called 活用語 or 用言, as opposed to words that never change, like nouns、which are called 体言. 用言 would include verbs and inflecting adjectives, like 難しい. 連体形 is the connecting form of verbs, and used to be formally distinct from the dictionary form (終止形), but in modern Japanese, the two are formally identical. The 待つs in 待つ人　and 人は待つ　look the same, but they have different grammatical functions, so they're classed separately. 待つだけだ is definitely grammatical, but 待つ here is 連体形.

Comment: @rdb ok thx for the explanation =D

Comment: @rdb btw how did you learn all these? the textbooks i use don't ever mention these stuff at all! do you have a book to recommend?

Comment: @Pacerier - We had to learn them for Classical Japanese to understand the old grammar. (Almost all of which I've completely forgotten, BTW) I don't know that they're particularly useful for a NSOE learner, because most textbooks have their own terms for verb conjugation,etc. If you're interested, though, just google up 日本語文法 or read the English language Wikipedia page titled "Japanese Grammar".

Comment: @rdb ok cool thx for the help

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, たった and ただ have exactly the same meaning, and are just variants, something like ばかり and　ばっかり。 As to the third example sentence, I'd venture to say that the  ただ there is the same ただ at the head of the snake.　(笑)

By the way, as Mr. Ito points out in comments above, if you meant to say, "It's just an ordinary snake" or the like, it needs to be　ただの蛇だ。　If you meant "It's only a snake", as in a case where you were expecting a Yeti, it would be 蛇だけだ。

Comment: btw is it true that ただ蛇だ means "It's only a snake" so basically it is the same as 蛇だけだ ? If so what is the difference in nuance between ただ蛇だ and 蛇だけだ ?

Comment: No. ただのX means "a mere X", "an ordinary X", etc. A "nothing special about it" X. 蛇だけだ is like this. Imagine you're in the Canadian wilderness, trying to track Bigfoot. You hear a rustling of leaves and turn toward the sound, hoping against hope that it's the sound of Bigfoot approaching. Instead, you see a huge viper noisily crawling toward you. You say: "Oh. It's just a snake." That is 蛇だけだ.

Comment: actually i was comparing it with ただ蛇だ, or do you mean to say that ただ蛇だ is the same as ただの蛇だ ?

Comment: ただ蛇だ, as has been pointed out earlier, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: ok thx for all the help =D

Comment: Well, I did not point it out (I just pointed out that ただ蛇だ is unnatural), but nice explanation.

Comment: Fair point. My apologies.

Comment: if ただ and たった are the same, could I say: ただのひとつの恋 and  たった子供だ? it's the same meaning?

Comment: If you want to say "my only love" and "a mere child", you've got them turned around. たったひとつの恋; ただの子供だ. If you want to say something else, please explain.

Comment: don't they have the same meaning? could ただ and たった be followed by nouns, numbers, verbs, adjetives, anything? both are used the same way?

Comment: You have to distinguish between ただの, たったの and ただ, たった. The の makes a big difference. Apart from that, they're pretty much the same.

Comment: but can I say: たった待つだけだ? (sorry, my problems with it werent solved yet) xD

Comment: As far as I know, anywhere you can say ただ, you can also say たった.

Comment: I just had the same question. I came across the paragraph "但し、三本足のカラスという外形そのものは、中国起源の「日烏」。中国では古来、太陽にはカラス、月にはウサギまたはヒキガエルが棲むとされて、それぞれの象徴となった。月日の事を「烏兎（うと）」と呼ぶ用例等にこれが現れている" and wondered why it wouldn't simply begin with ただ. Your answer doesn't address that though.